# Changes in Interface Builder are not showing in SImulator or Device

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiview, interface-builder, uiimageview

I have a view that I created using default buttons and background in Interface Builder.  The app runs properly.  I added .png background images to the view and to the buttons.  Build the app and run it and the updates do not show.

I've also tried something simple like changing the text of the button or add another button and the changes are not propagating.

I've cleaned targets, manually deleted builds in Finder, and have shutdown the computer.  What else am I missing?

Comment: Is your computer plugged in? I mean did you make sure you save the Interface Builder files. Building the application does not save IB files automatically although it does the other files.

Comment: Just to add one more comment I have seen cases where there were 2 copies of the same file. For instance myview.xib in the root directory of the project and myview.xib in the Classes directory of your project. If you edit the myview.xib in the Classes directory you probably wont see any changes reflected because the one in the root path is actually being referenced by the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might sounds easy - but are you sure you linked up the view to the view controller in Interface Builder? I've done it before where I just forget to link them

Comment: LOL - So since I built this IB file and utilized a tab bar, I've changed the view controller.  Instead of IB just failing when it could not find the VC it just kept using the old VC xib.  I since discovered the errors of my ways and rerouted the tab bar to the new xib file and voila the changes show up.

Comment: can u point exactly how to do this...this my first time with Xcode.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same experience. It turned out that I'd renamed my class and my xib file, but in another class I was creating the view with:

```
MyNewViewController *myNewViewController = [[MyNewViewController alloc]
 initWithNibName:@"MyOLDViewController" bundle:nil];
```

An oversight, but the surprising part to me is that when this Nib file didn't exist in my project, it managed to build successfully using a (presumably cached?) old Nib file... and the application happily ran, though showing an out of date interface.

Correcting what was passed to initWithNibName immediately corrected the issue for me.

Comment: Wish I could upvote you more. Just ran into this issue myself, very tricky to spot since the app compiles and runs just fine.

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same experience. For me the fix was to reset all content on the simulator.